# Immense loading time despite "positive" Google PageSpeed

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, pagespeed

**Challenge/problem**

`https://www.example.com/nachhilfe-hamburg/` takes **several seconds to load** (on my side 3-4 seconds before the first content/anything is visible).

If I check on it with **Google PageSpeed Insights** `https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/` it seems **ok**, at least not that much loading as it takes **in comparison** to other sites there, e.g. this very similar page has a much, much faster pagespeed `https://www.example.com/nachhilfe-online.php`. What causes this **immense loading time**?

**My thesis**

That it is because of the **redirects** and/or because sth is wrong with the `.htaccess`. For the `https://www.example.com/nachhilfe-hamburg/` page it is generically created on the basis of this in .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^nachhilfe-(hamburg)/$ /nachhilfe-stadt.php?stadt=$1 [NC,L]`

I have also **inspected and checked console**, but nothing there that seems to make this impact on the loading time.

Possibly relevant `.htaccess` parts:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Index\.php$ /index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^nachhilfe-(hamburg)/$ /nachhilfe-stadt.php?stadt=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Current Approaches that helped somewhat to increase page speed so far**

- Attached "defer" to all non-essential scripts (some Google scripts really subtracted some Google PageSpeed points)
- Converted the png to jpg
- Lazyloaded all images that are not shown at the top
- Looked for a solution to more efficiently imbed youtube (now with a placeholder that only on click loads the video and connects to youtube)

Answer (score 0):

On Google Chrome you have a `Network` tab (also in other browsers), and if you check in that tab, you will see the loading time for each resources that has been loaded to render the page, and you will see that you have 2 big resources that are taking a lot of times:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo
```

and

```
https://www.nachhilfe-team.net/nachhilfe.css
```

try to remove those and see if the loading time changes (obviously taking out the CSS is not to take in consideration, but you can think to something like integrating it on the header tag)

Comment: Thanks so much! The `https://www.nachhilfe-team.net/nachhilfe.css` is right before the `</head>` tag. Now those two lines are familiar, but they are also on the other pages, which are much, much faster like e.g. `https://www.nachhilfe-team.net/nachhilfe-kosten.php` (like instant loading in comparison to the other one). There has to be something else or my browser just decides to put some extra seconds on that specific URL.

Comment: @Franky2207 you can integrate the CSS in the header inline, so with `<head><style>...`, so that browser don't have to make a new request to fetch the CSS. Have you tried to remove the google font link?

Comment: thanks! I tried to remove the font, but it did not help. Now the strange part is that it runs so smoothly on very similar pages that use the same resources, load the same scripts etc. (like `https://www.nachhilfe-team.net/nachhilfe-online.php`). Still here it loads for an eternity, perhaps too many DB requests? This page has quite some. On Google PageSpeed it says "Initial Server response time 2,88sec" but it does not really show why it is that high.

Comment: @Franky2207 i cant figure out why actually, i see a high TTFB but it depends on connection, location and so on, i can only say that you should minimize JS files and resize the images to use a smaller size/quality, or using a lazy loader